# Capturing Python process's exit status in UNIX shell

Tags: python, linux, unix, terminal, return-value

I'm trying to figure out how to capture a return value from a python script in a *nix terminal. I'm using Linux.

So, for clarity, I have a converter script where you pass the Python script a number (as a string), it typecasts it, converts it and returns a number using `sys.exit(status_number)`. I understand that I am taking advantage of the return status, but it something that I would like to be able to do.

The only thing I cannot figure out is how to capture that return status in a variable. I know one can do `retVal=4`, but one cannot, however, expect something like `retVal=python foo.py 111` to work.

How can I do this?

Comment: FYI, `retVal=python foo.py 111` sets the environment `retVal` to the value `python` while executing `foo.py` with the argument `111`... so it is in fact valid shell syntax, even though it isn't what you actually _want_. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I never said the "not valid;" instead I said "it doesn't work [for my purposes]." or rather "one cannot expect [it] ... to work." :)

Comment: Sure -- I didn't mean to put words in your mouth, just to provide a point of interest. People often don't know what k=v pairs preceding a command on the same line actually do.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Great point! I apologize; I, perhaps, responded a little too harshly. Honestly, I didn't know what it did, but I knew that it didn't work for my purposes. It's a nice little snippet of information to know, though. I've only been "Linuxing" for about a month, so every nugget of knowledge is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Capturing the exit status**

```
python foo.py 111
retVal=$?
```

**2. Capturing both the exit status and standard output**

```
output=$(python foo.py 111)
retVal=$?
```

Comment: That captures **stdout**, not **exit status**.

Comment: I can do sys.stdout. Thanks

Comment: Improved my answer, thank you.  I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Much better now -- a full superset of my answer.

Comment: So - like I said - I am taking advantage of sys.exit(0) and passing in a number that is nonzero (and not one), but the $? only returns 0 or 1. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you call `sys.exit(x)`, you should find `x % 128` in `retVal`.

Comment: But the exit code should be some integer between 0 and 127

Comment: @Dylan, that's very much contrary to expected and documented behavior. Try `python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(3)'; echo $?` for a demonstration.

Comment: Well, I'm returning something > 127 (10000.0 to be precise). It prints, but it cannot capture the return value.

Comment: I guess I'll just have to use sys.stdout.print(var)

Comment: It is **impossible** to return an integer greater than 127 via the shell return code.

Comment: Well, like I said, it prints the return value to the screen but cannot capture the variable via $?

Comment: @Dylan, if it's going to the screen rather than being captured, that sounds like it's printing to stderr rather than stdout.